# Centering a object with an other disturbing

Tags: html, css

I got a problem to center one of my images. There is two images which makes the `#the_one_I_want_centered` follow the `text-align: center;` by being centered between the `#the_one_in_the_corner` and the left side of the browser. But I want it to be centered to the header. Is it someone there that can help me with this please!

I had also a bit simpler question and that is why my `#the_one_in_the_corner`does not push down my `#the_one_I_want_centered` underneath. I was wondering because it is an `display: block;` element witch should not let any other objects be in the same row as it, if I have understod it right! It is not something I want I was just wondering!

Thanks in advance!

```css
header {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#the_one_in_the_corner {
 float: right;
 margin: 10px;
}

#the_one_in_the_corner a {
 padding: 10px 10px 25px 30px;
}

#the_one_in_the_corner img {
 width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
   <div id="the_one_in_the_corner">
    <a href=""> <img src="a imag in the right corner"></a>
   </div>
   <a href="" id="the_one_I_want_centered"><img src="a image I want centered"></a>
 </header
```

Comment: no `img`s are showing, use [placeholder images](http://lorempixel.com) to properly describe your issue

Comment: your code seems like it's working for me http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/86u5oaf6/

Comment: have you tried to scale up and scale down. It is much more clear then that it is not centered?